# Correct way to access a file share

Tags: asp.net, permissions

What is the best way to access a resource in asp.net.
We have a network share that is accessible to only a particular domain user.
When I try to put impersonate in the web.config I get the error saying access denied asp.net temporary folder.
When I try to run the application pool under the same domain user I am not able to access the scripts styles and images folder.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Sounds like you're reading one site's contents from another site.

Comment: I am reading files in my asp.net web application from a file share server accessible to the domain user only. Whereas the web application resides on a different web server.